# Segmentation fault occurs when loading lightGBM model on M1 mac

Tags: python-3.x, segmentation-fault, pickle, apple-m1, lightgbm

Segmentation fault occurs when I try to load LightGBM model.
I have tried pickle (including protocol change), cloudpickle, joblib, and lightGBM save_model, however, I could not load the models.

Save model:

```
    model = lgb.LGBMRegressor(**kargs)
    model.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)
    with open(self.output_dir + 'models.pkl', "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(model, f, protocol=4)
    with open(self.output_dir + 'modelcl.pkl', "wb") as f:
        f.write(cloudpickle.dumps(model))
    pickle.dump(model, open(self.output_dir +
                'model.pkl', 'wb'), protocol=4)
    joblib.dump(model, f'{self.output_dir}model.joblib')
    joblib.dump(model, f'{self.output_dir}model.xz', compress=True)
    model.booster_.save_model(f'{self.output_dir}model.txt')
```

Load model:

```
joblib.load('path/model.xz')
joblib.load('path/model.joblib')
pickle.load(open('path/models.pkl', 'rb'))
pickle.load(open('path/modelcl.pkl', 'rb'))
pickle.load(open('path/model.pkl', 'rb'))
model = lgb.Booster(model_file='path/model.txt')
```

Environment: M1 Mac Monterely(12.0.1) Python 3.8.12 (conda), joblib==1.1.0, lightgbm==3.3.2.

Do you have any ideas what is going on here?
I think I should try saving the weights instead of saving the entire model, but don't know how on LightGBM.

Answer (score 6):

Solved this issue by installing lightgbm from conda `conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm` instead of using `pip install lightgbm`.
Probably it is not recommended to install lightgbm from pip.

Installed package is
`conda-forge/osx-arm64::lightgbm-3.3.2-py38hb2dfaa5_0`

Resource:
https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ.html#i-encounter-segmentation-faults-segfaults-randomly-after-installing-lightgbm-from-pypi-using-pip-install-lightgbm

Comment: I had created a model using `conda` but then loaded it in a `virtualenv` with the `pip install lightgbm` library and this caused a segfault. Uninstalling the pip package and switching to `conda` for all packages fixed it for me.